# AngularJS second query not hitting service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a factory that looks like this:

```
ChecklistApp.factory('Api', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
     return {
         Checklists: $resource('api/checklists', {}, { 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } }),
         Checklist: $resource('api/checklist', {}, { 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } }),
         AddChecklist: $resource('api/addchecklist', {}, { 'query': { method: 'POST' } }),
         UpdateChecklist: $resource('api/updatechecklist', {}, { 'query': { method: 'PUT' } })
     };
}]);
```

I have two controllers that use this factory
a list controller - which lists all checklists
an update controller - which displays one checklist and allows its detailed to be modified

The list controller assigns the data to a variable which in turn is bound to the UI as follows:

```
 $scope.search = function () {

            Api.Checklists.query({ Name: $scope.searchName },
            function (data) {
                $scope.checklists = data.checklists;
            }
        );
    };
```

In my edit controller I have the following update function which successfully updates the data in the DB and returns the user to the home (list) page.

```
var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Api) {
    $scope.action = "Update";
    var id = $routeParams.editId.replace(/\D+/, '');
    Api.Checklist.query({ id: id },
       function (qd) { $scope.item = qd.checklist; }
   );
        $scope.update = function () {
            Api.UpdateChecklist.save({ Id: $scope.item.id, Name: $scope.item.name },
                 function (data) {
                     $scope.item = data.checklist[0];
                     $scope.$apply();
                     $location.path('/#');  //Return to list controller
                 }
             );
        }
```

My issue is that after data is modified in my edit controller, I navigate back to the list control and although it hits the search query in the javascript it does not hit the service endpoint on the second call (skips it altogether) and the data is not refreshed (so the modified checklist has been updated on the DB but in the view on list control is remains as it was).

So my question is
How can I forcefully load the data again from the db using the same query that was run to load data initially ($scope.search in list control >> why does it skip this when the page is navigated to for the second time?) and/or alternatively is there a better way to just share the collection over multiple controllers (I read about nesting the scopes and putting the collection in the parent scope which could be accessed by both controllers but not sure if this is best practice or a suitable solution?)

Thanks

Comment: just put your Api.Checklist.query in a function. call it once in controller load. call it again after update.

Comment: Thats precisely what I'm doing. The issue is that although it hits the code to query the database again, it doesn't actually hit the get call on the server on the second time. edit: http://i61.tinypic.com/30t1f5w.png

Comment: Are you using IE? If yes, have a look at this issue on Github with different client and server side solutions for this problem: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1418

Comment: Phillipd switching to Chrome immediately solved the issue. Thank you so much for the response and link!